# jQuery delay is not working in custom plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, delay

I have created a custom jquery plugin.
which shows elements one after one.

I am simply using `delay()` to  do it one after.

But, only first delay works and after that all other elemts appear at the same time with first delay.

**My plugin**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.OneByOne = function( options ){

        var defaults = {
            startDelay:5,           
            duration: 1500,
            nextDelay: 2000
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){

            var o =options;
            var obj = $(this);                
            var a = $('a', obj);
            var delay = o.startDelay;

            obj.delay(delay).fadeIn(o.duration);
            delay += o.nextDelay;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It does return `this.each`, so every element gets it's own instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `delay` var outside the function:

```
(function($){
$.fn.OneByOne = function( options ){

    var defaults = {
        startDelay:5,           
        duration: 1500,
        nextDelay: 2000
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var delay = options.startDelay;

    return this.each(function(){

        var o =options;
        var obj = $(this);                
        var a = $('a', obj);

        obj.delay(delay).fadeIn(o.duration);
        delay += o.nextDelay;
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```